# Does one time work request interfere with periodic work request?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I have a periodic work request in my app which runs a ListenableWorker and I also have a one-time work request which runs the same Listenable worker. Would this affect the periodic work request? Say if 2 minutes are remaining for the next periodic work request but I run the one-time work request for the same work, would the periodic work request continue after the completion of the one-time work request?

Answer (score 3):

`OneTimeWorkRequest`s and `PeriodicWorkRequest`s don't interfere with each other as far as WorkManager is concerned. You can schedule one-time works and periodic works using the same Worker class. The Worker class you provide is basically the bag of operations you hand over to WorkManager to be *deferred*, as in *executed* as soon as every given constraint is met.
That being said, if you have a `ListenableWorker` subclass named `SyncWorker` and you schedule it to run once every hour periodically like this:

```kotlin
val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<SyncWorker>(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).build()
WorkManager.getInstance(...).enqueuePeriodicWork(periodicWorkRequest)
```

and you schedule a one-time work with the same class to run as soon as possible:

```kotlin
val oneTimeWork = OneTimeWorkRequest.from(SyncWorker::class.java)
WorkManager.getInstance(...).enqueue(oneTimeWork)
```

from WorkManager's point of view, these count as different, unrelated work instances.
Now to answer your question, WorkManager will just do its thing. It will run both work instances even if you start `SyncWorker` as a `OneTimeWorkRequest` 2 minutes before the scheduled runinng of the periodic work.

The only thing you have to consider is if running `SyncWorker` (or your equivalent of it) multiple times frequently could cause your data or business logic any harm.

Comment: Also, what does it mean when they say startWork() of listenable worker runs asynchronously? does that mean, it may start at any point of time at a given time frame? or when it starts, it may stop and resume at any point of time by creating another instance of the Listenable worker?

Comment: It means that `startWork` will run on a background thread by default (not blocking the UI thread). A new instance will only be created when the work fails for any reason, like the constraints being violated during the runtime of the work.

Sticking with the `SyncWorker` example, you probably need a network connection for syncing, so you run `SyncWorker`(s) with network availability constraints. If network becomes unavailable during a `SyncWorker` execution, the work will fail and will be rescheduled. In this case, every time this happens, a new `SyncWorker` instance is created.

Comment: I think you didn't catch my point quite right. The Listenable Worker class perform the work asynchronously, so I was asking what do they mean by performing work asynchronously in a class? Since the work starts from whatever is written in startWork() method, does that mean, everything written in start work is done asynchronously, how does asynchronous exactly work in a class. Btw, the startWork runs on the main thread (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#startWork())
So I think the periodic worker is setup only when the app is opened, unlike doWork()

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up with `ListenableWorker.startWork()` and `Worker.doWork()`, my bad.
`ListenableWorker.startWork()` is called on the main thread and gives you the opportunity to handle threading yourself. [Here's an example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker) (although written in Java) for doing some async work in `startWork()`. This only means that WorkManager will call your `ListenableWorker`'s `startWork()` on the main thread and you have to handle threading in it.

Comment: Otherwise, your `ListenableWorker` implementation will be handled by WorkManager just the same as any "smarter" implementation, like `Worker`, `CoroutineWorker` or `RxWorker`.
Take a peek at the mentioned classes here: [WorkManager repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work)

Comment: While running a listenable worker. What would happen if I don't set the Listenable future to success or failure, say I'm doing a database operation, and There's a scenario where upload need not happen (user is editing an image but does not save it). So Do I need to set it to success or failure? Is it necessary? Thanks a lot for the Doc link btw